# postgres convert string value to json

Tags: json, postgresql

I have following values in postgres table which need to be converted to json

```json
"[{""name"": ""xtz "S" "", ""strength"": ""25 x/1""}]"
"[{""name"": ""xtz "", ""strength"": ""25 x/1""}]"
```

I tried

- `::json` which gives error with these double quotes
- `to_json()` - it converts to json successfully but this output is of no use. It has lot of " in it. So when I do json_col -> key_name - I get all null values.

Comment: Can you please also post the expected output for the inputs? Should the quotes inside the string be removed or escaped?

Comment: REPLACE(your_json_string_field, '""', '"')::json. This will work if your json string is in a correct format. Right now this ""xtz "S" "" has an invalid JSON expression. You need to escape internal double quotes with a backslash like this \"S\"